# How to display stdout from TestResults in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, vstest

I am using the new yaml pipelines in Azure Devops. How do I display the StdOut logs from the test results in the Test Summary page for a pipeline run?

```
trigger:
- master
stages:
- stage: Tests
  jobs:
  - job: Tests
    steps:
    - script: dotnet test ./TestProject/ --logger "trx;LogFileName=TEST-results.trx"
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      inputs:
        testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
        failTaskOnFailedTests: true
        testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
        publishRunAttachments: true
        testRunTitle: 'Test Results'
```

In need stdout from the trx file to appear in the test summary page, example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRun xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Results>
    <UnitTestResult>
      <Output>
        <StdOut>
            Console logs appear here.
        </StdOut>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
</TestRun>
```

Comment: you dont need to do anything special in azure devops to display stdout. its displayed by default. so I suppose the problem is - your tests output nothing to stdout

Comment: Where is it displayed in Azure Devops? My test trx file does contain stdout as above. Everything else relating to the test run is displayed except this.

Comment: in the build log

Comment: I'm also trying to have the standard output in the .trx file displayed in the testrun rather then having to open the .trx file

Comment: Did you guys figure it out?

Comment: @LeonardoChaia check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719649/11365691

Comment: So there's no way to display them in the actual UI? I saw that answer but you have to download the trx to see the logs

Comment: Unfortunately that's what we had to do as well