# Azure Devops Pipelines Test Attachments for successful tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xunit.net

As noted here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops#tests-tab

> If you use the Visual Studio Test task to run tests, diagnostic output logged from tests (using any of Console.WriteLine, Trace.WriteLine or TestContext.WriteLine methods), will appear as an attachment for a **failed** test.

How can I enforce Azure Devops pipelines to publish attachments for successful tests?

**Update**

riQQ pointed to the another stackoverflow question:[Azure DevOps: Console output for green tests is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594777/azure-devops-console-output-for-green-tests-is-missing)
Proposed solution doesn't help me, because they solved using TestContext. We are using xUnit, and there is no TestContext for xUnit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps: Console output for green tests is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594777/azure-devops-console-output-for-green-tests-is-missing)

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. We are using xUnit, and there is TestContext for this.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686387/3241243. Alternatively, you can use the REST API to upload attachments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Thank you. Little bit complicated, and no time for now for ensure it works. I'll try to check this later.

Comment: Hi friend, just checking in to see whether the issue persists to block you. Any update feel free to let us know :)

Comment: No, this is one "nice to have" feature, thank you. I put it aside for now.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you still need any further assistance in this issue, you can share it here.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I enforce Azure Devops pipelines to publish attachments for
>   successful tests?

Sorry but as I know this is not supported behavior for VSTest Task. It's by design that only failed tests should have the log as attachment. And after my check, no extensions in [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) extends this kind of option.

So if you do want this option, you may consider using rest api like what riQQ suggests above. Or you can post a new feature request in [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), it it gets enough votes, the team would consider it seriously.

Hope it helps :)